# How to get a list of PHP core functions in order to write function wrapper

Tags: php, function, code-standards

I am trying to find a list of all the PHP core functions to write a proof of concept wrapper that standardizes all PHP function names into a consistent naming convention; in this case the PSR standards. Could anybody point me in the right direction to a reasonably complete function list along with their parameters?

I understand implementing this would add another layer of execution to a script, but its just a proof of concept to see how PHP would look if function names and parameter orders were standardized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want

```
 $functions = get_defined_functions();
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php

Good luck with that one!

Comment: Thanks ever so much? But did you mean getDefinedFunctions()? :)

Comment: I think I need to do a strReplace() to be sure ;)